# How can I assign a quality to a regression based on the number of data points?

Tags: regression, probability, dataset

Let's say I want to create a line of best fit to approximate the relationship between years of golf experience, and average golf score.

If I have only 4 data points, my line of best fit will have a lot of noise.  Is there an equation I can use to say how good the line of best fit is based on the number of data points are used to create it?

I guess we could say quality = theNumberOfDataPoints, but it doesn't seem like a linear relationship to me...  Is it maybe the square root of the number of data points?

Answer (score 3):

You mention your line of best fit, so you are thinking graphically.  You could also show the "quality" graphically.

In that case I would suggest plotting, along with the line of best fit itself, the upper and lower bounds of:

- the 95 % confidence interval (of the mean DV for different values of IV), and
- the 95 % prediction interval (of DVs predicted by the model from different values of IV).

There are some examples here:  http://www.medcalc.org/manual/scatter_diagram_regression_line.php

...and here is a simple one for data just like yours, with

- 95 % confidence interval bounds in red
- 95 % prediction interval bounds in orange

[image: graph with 95 % confidence interval bounds and 95 % prediction interval bounds plotted]

R code:
(

```
a <- c(5,10,15,20)
score <- c(95,82,75,69)
plot(a,score)
model.lm <- lm(score ~ a)
abline(model.lm,col="grey30")
frame = data.frame(a,score)
newx <- seq(0,25)
prdConf <- predict(model.lm, newdata=data.frame(a=newx), interval = c("confidence"), level = 0.95, type="response")
prdPred <- predict(model.lm, newdata=data.frame(a=newx), interval = c("prediction"), level = 0.95, type="response")
lines(newx,prdConf[,2],col="red",lty=2)
lines(newx,prdConf[,3],col="red",lty=2)
lines(newx,prdPred[,2],col="orange",lty=2)
lines(newx,prdPred[,3],col="orange",lty=2)
# with help from [https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-November/146285.html][3]
```

)

In my view plots like this should be actually be standard practice (especially the 95 % prediction interval) since it communicates the predictions made by the model so clearly, but I have only seen it rarely.

Comment: Can you define DV and IV?  I'm sorry if I missed that.

Comment: IV = independent variable (predictor variable (could refer to a manipulated variable or a covariate));  DV = dependent variable (outcome variable).  I am sure I am forgetting other possible terms.  Above, the IV is `a` (which is years of golf), and the DV is `score`.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the variance in your residuals and see how long it takes for that to begin to converge:

```
x=NULL; y=NULL; N=1e2; v=NULL
for(i in 1:N){
  new.x=runif(1)
  x=c(x,new.x)
  y=c(y,jitter(5*new.x))

  m=lm(y~x)      
  v=c(v, var(m$residuals))
}

plot(v, type='l', xlab='sample size', ylab='var(residuals)')
```

[image]

This isn't a measure of the quality of your model as much as it is a way of evaluating if you should expect your model to improve with more data. If you're just interested in model quality, for linear models the go-to evaluation of fit is generally the $R^2$ statistic, but there are certainly others. As Justin mentioned, you can reference the F statistic and p-value.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your model you should get an F statistic and p-value for the model overall (standard significance guidelines apply) and those also appear for each coefficient. They should take sample size into account.

Here's some more good information:
http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/r-lm-summary.html